# Get jenkins.BadHTTPException when try to get version info from jenkins run on docker

Tags: python, rest, jenkins

I installed docker container for Jenkins ver. 2.19.1.

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
f03c10935bb3        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   29 hours ago        Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   cocky_colden
```

Installed [`python-jenkins`](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module to access jenkins server.

I tried first code sample given in [docs](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#example-1-get-version-of-jenkins).

```
import jenkins

server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username='admin', password='mytoken')
user = server.get_whoami()
version = server.get_version()
print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))
```

But it gives error.

```
python /tmp/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    version = server.get_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 616, in get_version
    % self.server)
jenkins.BadHTTPException: Error communicating with server[http://localhost:8080/]
```

I check the docs which mentioned:

> From Jenkins vesion 1.426 onward you can specify an API token instead of your real password while authenticating the user against the Jenkins instance.

I used password instead of `token` but get same error.

I tried `curl`

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/testjob/build \
> --data token=mytoken \
> --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /job/testjob/build. Reason:
<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

I get token from *Name-> Configure -> Show API Token...*

Is there anything else I have to enable from jenkins side to access? means, API will get access to this server?

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it with: `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Comment: did it work for you as well?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Installing python-setuptools did not help in my case.

Comment: Actually, in my case it turned out to be a security problem in the Jenkins configuration. There was an option to disable all security, and when I did that, it worked. But please, if you do this, remember to re-enable security and figure out exactly which setting was the problem in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking the Jenkins security settings - those turned out to be the problem in my case.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 8):

There appears to be a minor bug in the **get_version()** function.

If the Jenkins server is setup with security enabled and IF the anonymous user doesn't have the 'Overall Read' rights then you need to pass the authorization key to urlopen()

i.e. in the file '**jenkins/__init__.py**', the **get_version()** function needs to be changed from:

```
def get_version(self):
    try:
        request = Request(self._build_url(''))
        request.add_header('X-Jenkins', '0.0')
        response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.timeout)
```

To:

```
def get_version(self):
    try:
        request = Request(self._build_url(''))
        if self.auth:
            request.add_header('Authorization', self.auth)
        request.add_header('X-Jenkins', '0.0')
        response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.timeout)
```

To find where this module is on your system, run python and enter:

```
import jenkins
jenkins.__file__
```

(I have reported the bug to the module authors)

Comment: This saved my day in a big way. Thank you so much for digging into this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Global Security >> Allow anonymous read access , worked for me

Comment: but for me, its not going to the page even :(